# Can Flash Builder 4 create a .war file?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, war

I'm doing Flex development in Flash Builder 4 and I haven't been able to find a way to get it to create a .war file.  The project creation wizard lets you select a web server to run your project in so I would expect it to be able to create a .war file.  The default behavior is just to copy everything into the project name under Tomcat's webapps/ directory.

Has anyone been able to find a way to create a .war file with Flash Builder 4?

Answer (score 1):

I have my project set to automatically publish to the GlassFish server so it doesn't normally create the .war file, but you can export the project to get it to create it.

It's under the `File` menu to `Export` and then you select the WAR file format.